# WebDAV query for Exchange 2007 Calendar: 400 Error

Tags: java, webdav, exchange-server-2007

I'm trying to get events from the Exchange calendar in Java. I'm using this query:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
<D:searchrequest xmlns:D=\ " DAV: \>
    <D:sql>
        SELECT "DAV:contentclass", "DAV:displayname"
        FROM "http://domain.com/Exchange/user/Calendar"
        WHERE "DAV:ishidden" = false"
        AND "DAV:isfolder" = false" "
    </D:sql>
</D:searchrequest>
```

However, I keep getting the 400 - Bad Request error code. Can someone tell me what is wrong with the syntax? Or is there something wrong with the approach?

Answer (score 0):

Is "http://domain.com/Exchange/user/Calendar" supposed to be a folder / collection? If that's the case, try to add a "/" at the end. I often get Bad Request errors when I try to use WebDAV methods on a folder while omitting the ending slash.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't help. Still a bad request. Moreover the first two lines look like this:   
    <?xml version="1.0"?><D:searchrequest xmlns:D = "DAV:">
I got them wrong in the previous post.

Comment: Also a question: Is it possible to use "*" to get everything, as in normal SQL?

Comment: I tried this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd159912(v=exchg.80), but still nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Using "JWebDAV for Exchange" library following SQL is equivalent

SELECT "DAV:contentclass","urn:schemas:calendar:dtstart","urn:schemas:calendar:dtend","http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/subject","http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/x1000001e" FROM "http://server/exchange/mailbox/Calendar" WHERE "DAV:contentclass" = 'urn:content-classes:appointment' AND "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/x10f4000b" = false

Comment: What are the "http://schemas..."? Isn't the query supposed to be made from fields?